# SP2013 - Tasks not showing description for certain users

Tags: 2013, permissions, tasks, task-list, bug

So I have an out-of-the-box task list on most of my department sub-sites. The task lists are using the standard Tasks content type. I've added an append-only comment field to the content type and turned on versioning.

The issue I'm having is that whenever a task has more than one user in the Assigned To field, anyone in a security group with Contribute rights can not see the data in the Description field unless they hit Edit or they click on one of the timestamps on the Append-Only Comments. This only happens for users in their respective department too. If an individual goes to another department sub-site, they can see tasks and its description.

Users with Read or Full Control permissions have no issues seeing the data in the Description field where there are multiple users in the Assigned To field.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I'm just missing something?

Comment: Did you change the rendering or is the webpart for the task list OOTB?

Comment: @MaxMelcher: The rendering is the same as far as I know (Standard). I have also tried Server rendering as well, but the issue persists. This seems to only happen when clicking on the Task itself. So when users are looking at the view form. I, also, added the Description column to the view, and confirmed users could see the values.